How to calculate the twist of an object B with respect to frame C if I know the twist of another object B rigidly attached to A
the problem I have is the following. I have a fixed reference frame in the world (C) that does not move from its place and I have two objects (A and B) that are moving and are rigidly joined to each other. I know the pose of B with respect to A through a transformation denoted as $G_b^a$ and I also know the pose and twist of A with respect to C denoted as $G_a^c$ and $\xi_a^c$. I need to calculate the pose and twist of B with respect to the fixed frame C. I calculate the pose of B with respect to C using the following formula $G_b^c = G_a^c * G_b^a$ but I cannot calculate the twist correctly.
I have tried applying the following formulas but they do not give me reasonable results.
$\xi_a^c = G_a^c * \xi_a^c * {G_a^c}^{-1}$
$\xi_a^c = {G_a^c}^{-1} * \xi_a^c * G_a^c$
The transformations denoted by $G$ are 4x4 matrices that contain the rotation and translation of one object to another in the following way:
\begin{equation}
G = \begin{bmatrix}
R &T\\0_{1\times3} &1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
The twist is composed of the skew-symmetric matrix of angular velocity and the linear velocity vector as follows:
\begin{equation}
\xi = \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{w} &v\\0_{1\times3} &0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
If someone could clarify for me how twist transformations work to solve this problem, I would greatly appreciate it. Greetings!
